# Identifying when the functi0n $\log(x!)-k\log((\frac{x}{2})!)$ is strictly increasing

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Let $x$ and $k$ be natural numbers. For which $k$ natural numbers the function $\log(x!)-k\log((\frac{x}{2})!)$ is strictly increasing?

Comment: Is it $\frac{x!}{2}$ or really $\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)!$?

Comment: @tofurind I edited the question.

Comment: okay, but what is the convention for odd $x$ here? Gamma function or just floor of $x/2$?

Comment: @tofurind Gamma function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Have you tried to shift the expression to $\log\left(\frac{x!}{(\frac{x}{2})!^k}\right)$?
Because $\log$ is strictly monotone its enough to study $\frac{x!}{(\frac{x}{2})!^k}$

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Do you think $k=3$ provides our conditions?

Comment: A rough inspection of the problem brings me to the notion that it is increasing for $k\in\{1,2\}$ and not for $k\geq 3$. It should be easy to prove. :)